# Facebook graph post related picture

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I just started using facebook's graph api.

I am using PHP SDK SammyK's wrapper and I wanted to grap all posts and related data :

```
 try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=id,message,picture', 'access-token');
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        return response($e->getMessage());
    }

    dd($response);
```

This works however I get this json

`{"id":"121484041600365_121825474899555","message":"Tessst","picture":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/13255950_121825428232893_8492293927724071052_n.jpg?oh=c87d7022bcbfd6b8fd072f50b9b26d63&oe=579CB729"}`

and when I try to access the picture url it says - Content not found. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/13255950_121825428232893_8492293927724071052_n.jpg?oh=c87d7022bcbfd6b8fd072f50b9b26d63&oe=579CB729` works fine for me, and shows a little image with some car on it.

Comment: Actually it's the only one that doesn't work for me, all the others work when I remove the trailing slashes, thanks a lot man you saved me a lot of time.